# NX Angular multiple libs with the same name

Tags: angular, typescript, nrwl-nx, nrwl

So I am using Angular with NX and I have the following groups `books` and `cars`. For both groups I want to create an `overview` lib with a table to view the books or cars.

So I create the lib under `libs/books/overview` next up I want to do the same for cars `libs/cars/overview`. But then I run into this issue:

```
Error: Project name already exists.
```

Do I need to name the libs like `books-overview`? Then I would create the following lib: `libs/books/books-overview`. `books` is redundant so it doesn't seem like the best option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The folder name does not have to be same as the app. Instead, you could create parent folder for each dash separated part of your library name.

You can create lib with name  `'books-overview'` in folder `books/overview`.

---

Running the command with the folder structure as name, it correctly decides on the name. Running

```
npx ng generate @nrwl/workspace:library --name=books/overview
```

will generate library `'books-overview'` in folder `books/overview`.

---

For example this is config of our application (we also use nx):

```
// angular.json excerpt
"api-java-model": {
  "projectType": "library",
  "root": "libs/api/java/model",
...
},
"api-java-client": {
  "projectType": "library",
  "root": "libs/api/java/client",
...
```

That way you don't have a folder collision.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option here is create a folder `overviews` with the libs inside. For instance:

`libs/overviews/cars`

`libs/overviews/books`

Comment: Thanks but I don't think that this is a good solution. Grouping libs by their domain provides a clean architecture. But with that solution you have a special pattern, that breaks the clean structure